# How to create / set custom color of table cells and borders in iText 7?

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

I need to create a table which has custom colored cells and borders. There are a few constants defined in the `Color` class, but what I need a custom color. I need #a6cb0b as the background color for the header and border lines with color code #cccccc. How do I set them?

```
Table table = new Table(new float[]{1,1,1});
Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.add(new Paragraph("TITLE"));
cell.setBackgroundColor(Color.???);
table.addCell(cell);
...
...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to find out how to create colors, is to check the [API docs](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/). When you go to the page that describes the ['Color'](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/color/Color.html) class, you see that it has several subclasses:

- [DeviceGray](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/color/DeviceGray.html)
- [DeviceRgb](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/color/DeviceRgb.html)
- [DeviceCmyk](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/color/DeviceCmyk.html)
- ...

It seems that you want to create an RGB color, hence you need `DeviceRgb`:

```
Color headerBg = new DeviceRgb(0xA6, 0xCB, 0x0B);
Color lineColor = new DeviceRgb(0xCC, 0xCC, 0xCC);
```

You can use the `color` object to set the color of borders, backgrounds, etc...

Comment: I did read the API docs for 'Color' class but I could not figure out the way I need to pass the color values to DeviceRgb. Anyways Thank you @BrunoLowagie.

Comment: I am new to iText so this might be a very simple question. The `cell` class has a `setBackground()` function that can be used to set the color of the background. But how do I set the Border of the Cell to `lineColor`? I tried `cell.setBorder(new Border().setColor(lineColor));`. @BrunoLowagie

Comment: You can't create a `Border` instance, can you? You need to create a *specific* border, such as a `SolidBorder` or a `DottedBorder`. You may also want to specify a width, for instance `new SolidBorder(lineColor, 3)`.

Comment: Thanks once again. @BrunoLowagie